# How to calculate round trip time for an ICMP packet

Tags: c++, c, qt, icmp, roundtrip

I'm writing some C code in Qt5 to send ICMP echo packet to detect a machine. I don't know how to calculate round trip time.

my code seems not working properly:

```
Before sending:
struct timezone tz;
struct timeval  ts;
gettimeofday( &ts, &tz );
ts.tv_sec  = ts.tv_sec;
ts.tv_usec = ts.tv_usec;
bcopy(&ts, &(pkt.icmp.data[0]), sizeof(struct timeval)); // target host will modify this
bcopy(&ts, &(pkt.icmp.data[8]), sizeof(struct timeval));

After receiving:
struct timezone tz;
struct timeval  ts1;
struct timeval  ts2;

bcopy(&(pkt.icmp.data[8]), &ts1, sizeof(struct timeval));
gettimeofday( &ts2, &tz );
round trip time = (ts2.tv_sec - ts1.tv_sec) +
                     1e-6 * (ts2.tv_usec - ts1.tv_usec);
```

Anything wrong?

Thanks

Edit:
this is the receiving function:

```
void CPingReceiver::dataProcess(struct icmp_packet pkt)
{
struct timezone tz;
struct timeval  ts1;
struct timeval  ts2;

bcopy(&(pkt.icmp.data[8]), &ts1, sizeof(struct timeval));
gettimeofday( &ts2, &tz );

QHostAddress ha  = QHostAddress(ntohl(pkt.ip.saddr));
foundItem.first  = ha.toString();// (ts2.tv_sec * 1000 + ts2.tv_usec / 1000) - (ts1.tv_sec * 1000 + ts1.tv_usec / 1000)
foundItem.second = tr("%1 ms").arg(((ts2.tv_sec - ts1.tv_sec) +
                                   (ts2.tv_usec - ts1.tv_usec) / 1000000));

emit sendToListener(foundItem);

// qDebug() << addr << endl;

// now send the data to ARP Worker Singleton
// PING results will send its data to ARP Worker Singleton as well
// same for hostname, vendor and netbios, open ports
}
```

Here is sending function:

```
/************************************************************************
 * Build ICMP Header
 ************************************************************************/
pkt.icmp.type       = ICMP_ECHO;        // icmp echo */
pkt.icmp.code       = 0;                // only valid value for echo or echo reply */
pkt.icmp.checksum   = 0;
pkt.icmp.identifier = ICMP_IDENTIFIER;  // the id we'll be using to distinguish our data from other icmp packets */
pkt.icmp.sequence   = 1;                // Start from 0
struct timezone tz;
struct timeval  ts;
gettimeofday( &ts, &tz );
bzero(pkt.icmp.data, ICMP_MTU);
bcopy(&ts, &(pkt.icmp.data[0]), sizeof(struct timeval));
bcopy(&ts, &(pkt.icmp.data[8]), sizeof(struct timeval));

pkt.icmp.checksum   = calcsum((quint16 *)(&pkt.icmp), sizeof(pkt.icmp));
```

This is what I got:

```
"192.168.0.21" "----" "F0:7D:68:04:49:86"  // ARP reply
"192.168.0.28" "----" "00:19:5B:0D:30:85"  // ARP reply
"192.168.0.30" "----" "00:04:20:2C:83:34"   // ARP reply
"-------------PING reply-----------------" "192.168.0.21" "----" "-8316290828429 ms" 
"192.168.0.26" "----" "74:44:01:D3:07:E0"   // ARP reply
"-------------PING reply---------------" "192.168.0.26" "----" "-8316290828429 ms" 
"-------------PING reply---------------" "192.168.0.30" "----" "-8316290828429 ms" 
"192.168.0.23" "----" "C8:60:00:1A:B0:BC"   // ARP reply
"-------------PING reply---------------" "192.168.0.23" "----" "-8316290828429 ms"
```

Comment: You could use the [`timersub`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timercmp) function.

Comment: struct timezone tz;
    struct timeval  ts1;
    struct timeval  ts2;
    struct timeval  ts3;

    bcopy(&(pkt.icmp.data[8]), &ts1, sizeof(struct timeval));
    gettimeofday( &ts2, &tz );
    timersub(&ts2, &ts1, &ts3);

    QHostAddress ha  = QHostAddress(ntohl(pkt.ip.saddr));
    foundItem.first  = ha.toString();
    foundItem.second = tr("%1 ms").arg(ts3.tv_usec);"192.168.0.30" "----" "-8316290828429423476 ms"

Comment: Why don't you use the `ts` variable you filled in, instead of the network data?

Comment: The documentation for `bcopy` says to use `memmove` instead.  (Here you could safely use `memcpy`)

Answer (score 1):

The `gettimeofday()` function provides a time value in native byte order, not necessarily in network byte order.  Do **not** call `ntohl()`.

```
double round_trip_time = (ts2.tv_sec - ts1.tv_sec) +
                         1e-6 * (ts2.tv_usec - ts1.tv_usec);
```

Comment: I got this:"192.168.0.21" "----" "-5.37912e+17 ms"

Comment: That's a very suspicious number.  It's around 10^48 s, which means that you have a 64-bit count for seconds which is getting screwed up.  Make sure you never use `htonl()` on a 64-bit value, because `htonl()` operates on 32-bit values.

Comment: I'm running 64-bit fedora 18, but I deleted htonl already. Thanks!

Comment: I did this: foundItem.second = tr("%1 ms").arg((quint32)(((ts2.tv_sec - ts1.tv_sec) + (ts2.tv_usec - ts1.tv_usec) / 1000000))); But still getting: "192.168.0.30" "----" "3060823923 s"

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using [QElapsedTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qelapsedtimer.html)?